# load data between prolog and db2

Tags: prolog

I am just learning prolog. I have a task ahead. I have to insert some data in to a database like Db2 express c v9.7.1 using Prolog ODBC INterface. I know there are some example predicates(SWI-PROLOG) by documentation swi-prolog home

open_wordnet :- 
    odbc_connect('WordNet', _, 
                 [ user(jan), 
                   password(xxx), 
                   alias(wordnet), 
                   open(once) 
                 ]). 
I do not know how to exactly use these predicates and show a working example. Can anyone please tell me how do I exactly use these to insert data into a database like Db2 express C v9.7.1 once etablished the connection between prolog and db2 from into eclipse sdk-win 32. Write me at the address mail intriguer@alice.it.

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a few years ago i have done something like that; the database was about academic relationships/info and i used prolog and ODBC (plus xpce for the gui).

first i opened a connection to the database:

```
fconn(C):-
    odbc_connect('academia_info', C, [user(academia_info_user), 
                  password(secret), alias(academia_info), open(once)]).
```

open(once) is used to avoid reconnecting to the db and C is a handler

then i used this predicate to submit queries:

```
%run_statement(+SQL,-Row)
rs( SQL, Row):-
   fconn(Connection),
   odbc_query(Connection, SQL, Row).
```

and if i wanted all the solutions I did this

```
%returns all solutions (findall)
%rsall(+SQL,-Rows)
rsall(SQL, Rows):-
    findall(Row,rs(SQL,Row), Rows).
```

for example:

```
rsall('SELECT * FROM institution', D).
```

this predicate prepares a SQL query:

```
prep(SQL, Type, Row,Values):-
    fconn(Connection),
    odbc_prepare(Connection, SQL, Types,Q), %uses the types of the parameters to prepare Q
    odbc_execute(Q,Values,Row). %executes Q by replacing the parameters with their values
```

for example:

```
prep('UPDATE professor SET title = ? WHERE id IN (SELECT professor.id FROM professor, researcher, "hadPosition" WHERE professor.id = researcher.id AND professor.id = "hadPosition".researcher_id AND hadPosition.title = ? AND professor.title=? GROUP BY professor.id HAVING sum("hadPosition".end_date - "hadPosition".start_date) > ?*365 )',
         [varchar,varchar,varchar, integer],_, [MT, LT,LT, Y]).
```

where ?s are replaced by the values [MT,LT,LT,Y]

here I delete some stuff

```
delete(ID,Table):-
    swritef(S,'DELETE FROM %t WHERE id = ?', [Table]),
    prep(S, [integer], _ , [ID]).
```

prepare a statement to insert new values (it's executed later):

```
prep('INSERT INTO professor (id, title) VALUES (?,?)', [integer, varchar], _, [ID,T]).
```

btw odbc_query returns a value with the following format row(D1,D2,D3,....,Dn)
so perhaps you will have to convert it to a list.

i hope that the examples above might help.. although i have kinda forgotten the details :/
anyway, the whole project can be found [here](http://users.ntua.gr/el06009/site/things/db.zip) but the code is not so readable